# Is the iPhone "cron-able"?

Tags: iphone, cron, scheduling

Note - I have not delved very deeply into Apple's iPhone SDK yet.

However, based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350067/how-can-i-run-an-app-at-a-specified-time-on-the-iphone) asked recently, I'm wondering if, since the iPhone is running some stripped-down edition of Mac OS X if it doesn't have a crontab feature.

If so, how would you access it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that cron runs by default on the iPhone, you just need to be able to edit the crontab file - <strike>either</strike> the root one <strike>or the user one</strike> but not the user one apparently.

There are issues with sleep and cron, but there's a good discussion at that link.

Comment: Is there any way to access crontab on an un-jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: I don't believe so. Here's hoping that Apple will put timers and scheduled tasks into a future version of the iPhone OS / SDK, but for tasks that are network polling I think they will want you to use the push notifications feature in the next release.

Comment: btw - has this changed in iOS 4.3?

Comment: @warren I've got an iPad on jailbroken 4.3.1 firmware and Apple still hasn't added any crontab support in the iOS SDK. Ad@m

Comment: The link is not working for me :/ I'm jailbroken already, and can't find it...

Answer (score 7):

The iPhone does run cron - but you won't be able to use it in any application developed solely with the SDK. There is absolutely no support for background process or background launching via alarms or timers (e.g. crontab).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use cron on an un-jailbroken iPhone.

Maybe you could take advantage of the Push Notification service: Have cron (or some other scheduler) running on another machine which sends notifications to the phone at the appropriate time.

Comment: And hope that you don't have an application like one I shelved that requires waking up every minute!

Comment: You could use the PushThePage app on the iDevice and a shell script automatically run on a Linux or Mac box that uses curl to open the "send to device" link on PushThePage's Website with a message where the page url should be. Ad@m

Answer (score 4):

It appears the iPhone no longer runs crons nor has crontab (2012, iPhone 4s jailbroken, iOS 5.01)